# How do I upload a jpg file with image map onto the SharePoint website and render it properly?

Tags: sharepoint, imagemap

I have to display an image map in a SharePoint website.
I created the image map with hot links using html code in a notepad and then re-saved the file as a html file. When I launch it from the desktop, it is rendering the jpg image with the hot spots (when when clicked lead to the SharePoint links) properly, but when I upload the html image into SharePoint, it is not rendering the jpg file with the hot spots.

Will appreciate if someone can answer me how to solve this problem.

Comment: maybe javascript code there? or something like script that SharePoint didn't allow that? possible for you to paste some CODES here ...???? (no all of your html code)